# Подскажите, как можно хранить 500 млн строк. Какую использовать базу данных?

Tags: база-данных

Доброго времени суток,

Проблема встала такая: нужно где-то хранить данные. Ожидается примерно 500 млн строк. Это некая база ключей на разных языках, со своими цифрами, вида просмотры, частоты и т.д.

Периодически базу нужно обновлять: добавлять новые строки, обновлять счетчик фраз. Из базы нужно делать выборки, вида: LIKE "%word%" (поиск совпадений в слове), сортировка по счетчикам, или еще что.

Так вот начал я все это дело заполнять в SQLite, а теперь думаю, что ему наверно тяжеловато с такими объемами будет. И каждая выборка будет занимать продолжительное время.

Подскажите, куда смотреть? Как правильно выбрать БД, чтобы потом не мучаться.

Comment: **PostgreSQL** я бы использовал) как для не больших, так и для крупных хранилищ.. **SQLite** на мое, возможно не объективное мнение, годится для специфических задач, если это что-то сложнее калькулятора, то лучше sql+...

Comment: `LIKE "%word%"` - для этого нужен полнотекстовый поиск (fulltext search). Поэтому берите СУБД, в которой имеется такая возможность. Или берите специализированный FTS движок, типа Lucene, Solr, Elastic.

Comment: Недостаточно вводных данных, чтобы определить, какая именно СУБД нужна. PS: sqlite прекрасно может справиться с таким количеством строк. PPS: FTS в sqlite есть.

Comment: А если использовать Mysql? Он способен вытянуть 500 млн строк? Просто я не работал с PostgreSQL, хотя много о ней слышал.

@Alexander Petrov, Мне еще важно время операции. Как долго sqlite будет думать над какой-либо процедурой. Если будут делаться разные SELECTы в течении дня, по частоте, количеству, сортировка там, группировка по фразам. Таблица простая: word VARCHAR, freq INTEGER, count INTEGER, date DATE

Регулярно база будет обновляться данными UPDATE и дополняться новыми INSERT. Максимум данных планируется 1 млрд.

Comment: **Недостаточно вводных данных**. Сколько будет запросов к БД: тысячи в секунду или несколько в день? Сколько будет клиентов? Много ли будет вставок/обновлений? Таблица одна-единственная?

Comment: Примерно 1-10 запросов в секунду на INSERT, и на SELECT 5-10 запросов в минуту. 

Будет еще 2 таблица, как дополнение к первой. Там будут разные словоформы, производные от первой таблицы. Где будет также всего 3 колонки: parent_id INTEGER, word VARCHAR, freq INETEGER.
Она будет в запросах тоже участвовать в виде JOIN

Comment: Такую нагрузку потянет практически любая РСУБД. Единственная проблема, которую я вижу: `"%word%"` - поиск в _середине_ фразы - тут никакой индекс не поможет. Вернее, нужен специиальный индекс, как в FTS и т. п.

Comment: Обсуждение длится уже день. И продолжать его можно ещё долго и безрезультатно. Поэтому просто установите пару-тройку разных СУБД (docker run postgres), залейте несколько миллионов строк, создайте индекс, соберите статистику (это важно!) и погоняйте запросы. В результате чего примете решение, годится эта СУБД или нет. PS: не забудьте про статистику.